# Properly outputting the total of a counter in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a working program that randomly generates a total of 100 asteriks arbitrarily on 10 rows. However, I am having a hard time printing the total of asteriks on each row. On the last line of code (which is commented out), I tried what I thought would be the first step to getting it to work. I need the output to look similar to this:

```
14| * *
13| * *
12| * * * *
11| * * * *
10| * * * * * *
 9| * * * * * *
 8| * * * * * * * *
 7| * * * * * * * *
 6| * * * * * * * * * *
 5| * * * * * * * * * *
 4| * * * * * * * * * *
 3| * * * * * * * * * *
 2| * * * * * * * * * *
 1| * * * * * * * * * *
  -------------------
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Mine instead looks as followings:

```
0 |************
1 |*************
2 |******
3 |*************
4 |******
5 |*********
6 |*********
7 |*********
8 |************
9 |***********
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

```
import java.util.Random;

public class QuestionTwoAssignmentOne2018 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random bytes = new Random(); //take this out of the loops as mentioned in the comments
        int count = 100; //keep track of 100 '*'s
        int arr[] = new int[100];

        for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
            arr[a] = bytes.nextInt(10); // 
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
            int bcount = 0;

            for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
                if (arr[a] == i)
                    bcount++;   
                }

                System.out.print(i + " |");

                for (int c = 0; c < bcount; c++ )
                    System.out.print("*");

                System.out.println();

                // System.out.println(bcount + " |");        // MY ATTEMPT        

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying print the total number of ateriks in each row in my program... i provided the output if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get desired output because you are using that commented line inside the loop.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class QuestionTwoAssignmentOne2018 {
private static final int NUM = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random bytes = new Random(); // take this out of the loops as mentioned
                                    // in the comments
    int count = 100; // keep track of 100 '*'s

    int arr[] = new int[100];
    for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
        arr[a] = bytes.nextInt(10); //

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)

    {
        int bcount = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
            if (arr[a] == NUM - i)
                bcount++;
        }

        System.out.print(NUM - i + " |");
        for (int c = 0; c < bcount; c++)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print("  "); // for better view
    for (int i = 0; i < (NUM * 2) - 1 ; i++)
        System.out.print("-");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("  "); // for better view
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
        System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

}

And I wrote the more generic code for you. You may just change constant NUM to arrange number of rows.

Comment: how do i get one line to be the total number of rows i.e: (0-9) and the other to be the total number of asteriks in each row? if you get what i mean..

Comment: I couldn't get what you ask exactly.